# Isomorphism of 2 algebras with 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}$ - field,
A = $\begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{F} & \mathbb{F}\\
  0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$,
B = $\begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{F} & 0\\
  \mathbb{F} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

I know that A and B are not isomorphic $\mathbb{F}$-algebras.
But will they isomorphic if I join 1 to $\mathbb{F}$-algebras:
$ A \oplus \mathbb{F} \bullet 1 \cong B \oplus \mathbb{F} \bullet 1$?

Comment: Why are they not isomorphic? Are they only *dually* isomorphic? (I.e. with reversed multiplication, $A^{op}\cong B$?) And please put a question mark at the end of your question.

Comment: It seems $A\oplus\Bbb F\cdot1\cong\pmatrix{\Bbb F&\Bbb F\\0&\Bbb F}$ while $B\oplus\Bbb F\cdot1\cong\pmatrix{\Bbb F&0\\ \Bbb F&\Bbb F}$, if that's of any help.